# Log exact exception origin and its backtrace at_exit in Ruby

Tags: ruby, exception, logging

I want to always log as much information as possible about exception that caused multithreaded ruby script's crash. I know there is `at exit` method and that the latest error is accessible in `$!`

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')
at_exit { logger.info "Exception that killed us is: #{$!}" }

threads =
  10.times.with_object([]) do |_, t|
    t << Thread.new { sleep 1 }
  end

threads << Thread.new { raise RuntimeError, 'We died' }
threads.each(&:join)
```

However, in log this looks like:

```
I, [2018-08-23T10:40:47.307841 #6772]  INFO -- : Exception that killed us is: We died
```

Is there a way to add more information, like backtrace, file and line number to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backtrace already contains file and lineno, [`$@` global](https://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/globals_rdoc.html) contains a backtrace.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [English based names](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/English/rdoc/English.html) for these exception messages:

```
require 'logger'
logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')
at_exit { logger.info "Exception that killed us is: #{$ERROR_INFO} - #{$ERROR_INFO.class} - #{$ERROR_POSITION}" }

threads =
  10.times.with_object([]) do |_, t|
    t << Thread.new { sleep 1 }
  end

threads << Thread.new { raise RuntimeError, 'We died' }
threads.each(&:join)
```

Keeping in mind that `$ERROR_INFO` will get you the exception message when provided else the exception class itself. while `$ERROR_INFO.class` gets you the exception class. In your case `$ERROR_INFO` will result in `'We died'`.